# How can I run small C# code in Logic Apps?

Tags: c#, azure, xslt, azure-logic-apps

I have XML data in my POST Request which needs to perform some mapping based on C# code. It's basically reading the XML data and performs some updates on certain fields while using multiple C# code methods. Approximately 3 methods with 300 lines of code. How can I do this in Logic Apps?

Comment: At least post representative samples and whatever you have tried.

Comment: Put the code in a Function App and call the function from the Logic App.

Comment: I like you definition of small.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by invoking azure functions from your logic apps. See here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions